# Importing project class in static library iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, import, static-libraries

I have a static library project and an iOS project in one workspace. There is a class `FCPlayerData` in the static library. I subclass `FCPlayerData` as `PlayerData` in the iOS project.

The problem:

I need the static library to reference `PlayerData` (the subclass) that is in the iOS project but it doesn't recognise any of the properties of `PlayerData` and when CMD clicked, says "Symbol not found". How can I import the subclass from the iOS project into the static library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into the answers, however, in my situation a category is not suitable.

I found a solution:

In the static library, I created a property in my `FCReferences` class as such: `@property(strong, nonatomic) id playerData;`. Now, in the static library, I only need to access the core properties of `FCPlayerData` so to access them, I cast it using `((FCPlayerData*)playerData).myProperty`. In the iOS project, I need to access the additional properties of the subclass, so I cast it as `((PlayerData *)playerData).additionalProperty`.

Note: `PlayerData` is a subclass of `FCPlayerData`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add few methods to the FCPlayerData you can use Categories to add those methods directly to the FCPlayerData.
Look here for more on categories: http://krodev.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/objective-c-categories/ or here http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/03/27/objective-c-lesson-8-categories/

Comment: I need to extend the encode and decode methods of NSCoding and add a few more properties. The object is used mainly for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

If `FCPlayerData` is a subclass of `PlayerData` it would be safe to pass an instance of type `FCPlayerData`.

Or you could add the header and implementation files for the subclass to the project but that would cause a cross dependency between your project and the static library.